# Jordan canonical form in Lang's Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

In Lang's algebra on pp.559, he writes of the nilpotent part of a matrix $M$:

"We observe also that the only case when the matrix $N$ is $0$ is when all the roots of the minimal polynomial have multiplicity $1$.  In this case, if $n = \dim E$, then the matrix $M$ is a diagonal matrix, with $n$ distinct elements on the diagonal."

Isn't the nilpotent part of *any* diagonal matrix zero?  In particular, consider the identity matrix.  In that case the minimal polynomial has roots of multiplicity one, but the elements on the diagonal are all the same!

Comment: Yes, you're right: the nilpotent part of *any* diagonalizable matrix is $0$. Perhaps there's some context missing here, or maybe there's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the last sentence in your quotation is wrong.

The condition that the minimal polynomial of $M$ has no multiple root is equivalent to the matrix $M$ being diagonalizable;  of course, every $n\times n$ diagonalizable matrix has trivial nilpotent part, but not necessarily $n$ distinct eigenvalues.

The source of the confusion might be having mistaken *minimal polynomial* with *characteristic polynomial* in the preceding sentence.